# Sorting rows and leaving blanks in their position

Tags: excel, powerquery, data-cleaning, m

I have the following table with two columns:

| Date | Book Title |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2022 |  |
|  | Title1 |
|  | Title2 |
| 03.01.2022 <- unsorted |  |
| 02.01.2022 |  |
|  | Title3 |
| 02.01.2022 |  |
|  | Title4 |

The `Date` rows work as a sort of sub-header for the column `Book Title`, but as you can see some dates aren't in ascending order. The duplicates aren't an issue.

My goal is to achieve the following (note the unchanged blank cells in `Date`):

| Date | Book Title (remains unchanged) |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2022 |  |
|  | Title1 |
|  | Title2 |
| 02.01.2022 <- fixed sorting |  |
| 02.01.2022 |  |
|  | Title3 |
| 03.01.2022 <- fixed sorting |  |
|  | Title4 |

However, what happens when I sort by ascend normally is that all blank cells are collected at the top of the table. I want to retain the blank cells where and as they are.

I managed to do this directly on Excel by hiding the blanks in `Dates`, sorting the remaining cells with the dates, and then unhiding the blank cells. This let me keep the blank cells as they are, and sort the dates only within the cells that are already populated.

How could I achieve this on Power Query instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in powequery

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type", "Date", "Date - Copy"),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Duplicated Column",{"Date - Copy"}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filled Down", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Added Index",{{"Date - Copy", Order.Ascending}, {"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Date - Copy", "Index"})
in   #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

or

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Index",{"Book Title"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each ([Date] <> null)),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}}),
Resort = {Table.ToColumns(#"Sorted Rows"){0}} & {Table.ToColumns(#"Filtered Rows"){1}},
Resorted=Table.FromColumns(Resort,{"Date","Index"}),

#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Index",{"Date"}),
#"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns2", each ([Book Title] <> null)),

Combined =  Resorted & #"Filtered Rows2",
#"Sorted Rows1" = Table.Sort(Combined,{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows1",{"Index"})

in #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The second code snippet worked just as I wanted. Just a short FYI, you might've mixed up the order of the screenshots. When I run the first code snippet I get the result of the *second* image, the one with a blank cell between the duplicate dates. When I run the second code snippet, I get what shows up in the first table.

Comment: Image reversal fixed. Thanks